# Как в python взять Email после текста и заменить его на другой?

Tags: python

Необходимо в текстовом файле найти текст "другая почта:" и в этой строке взять email
Далее заменить найденный email (в данном случае к примеру test123_8080@mail.ru), и заменить его вместо test_8080@mail.ru, подставив к паролю.

Пример текстового файла:

```
пользователь текст все дела
test_8080@mail.ru:12345
как дела привет

другая почта: test123_8080@mail.ru
==============================

пользователь текст все дела
test@mail.ru:12345
как дела привет

другая почта: test123@mail.ru
==============================
```

Comment: что конкретно у вас не получается? или это вы нам задание даете?

Comment: не понимаю как дойти до другая почта, потом посчитать расстояние и дойти выше до первой почты и заменить её

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/QFBx9c/1

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо

Comment: @splash58 подскажите пожалуйста как должна выглядеть регулярка чтобы оставить только "test_8080@mail.ru:12345" ?

Comment: если пробелов нет `[^\s]+:[^\s]+`